# SSL Certificate Does not work with subdomains other than www on AWS ALB

Tags: ssl, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-application-load-balancer, aws-certificate-manager

I just configured SSL certificate on a domain that routes to my Elastic Beanstalk ALB.

However, it seems like the SSL lock icon does not show for domains with subdomain other than www.

for example, the lock icons shows for `www.myDomain.com` and `myDomain.com`. But it does not show for `api.myDomain.com` or `www.api.myDomain.com`.

How I set it up:

I went on AWS Certificate manager and requested for SSL certificate on my domain. Then, I went to Route 53 and created a record alias to my elastic beanstalk load balancer with subdomains of `www`, ``, and `api`. I don't know why but only `www.myDomain.com` and `myDomain.com` shows the ssl lock, not for `api.myDomain.com`.

The reason I want to do this is because I want to use `api.myDomain.com` for my API and `myDomain.com` for my front end app. Is this best practice?

can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You have to provide exact details of how you set your domains and ssl certificates. Your current question lacks details and is unclear.

Comment: Hey Marcin! I just updated my post with the steps on how I set up SSL certificate.
I went on AWS Certificate manager and requested for SSL certificate on my domain. Then, I went to Route 53 and created a record alias to my elastic beanstalk load balancer with subdomains of www, ``, and api. I don't know why but only www.myDomain.com and myDomain.com shows the ssl lock, not for api.myDomain.com.